# In ubuntu 22.04 pm2 commad always stuck at [PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/home/$USER/.pm2

Tags: reactjs, node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQWJU.jpg)

Here is the screenshot

i have reinstalled PM2 and Downgraded it's version both didn't work.

npm uninstall -g pm2

Give full permission to ~/.PM2 and still Getting the error

chmod 777 ~/.pm2

npm i -g pm2@5.2.2  downgraded

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.